# Generate a random two-dimensional array of non-repeating numbers, Java

Tags: java, arrays, random, multidimensional-array

The user will type in the number for **i** (variant), then the number for **j** (elements for every variant), and finally the maximum value possible (maxElem).
Using the inputed values, the task is to generate nonrepeating random numbers (**nonrepeating in a variant, meaning for i**, but the numbers may repeat during the entire array).

For example, a successful output giving the input **3 (i), 5 (j), 9 (maxElem)**, would be:

**4**|8|1|7|9

3|8|2|**4**|5

2|6|**4**|8|5

As you may notice, the number 4 repeats itself during the entire array for 3 times (allowable). But, for **i=0**, number 4 is unique.

Please, guide me what would be the changes to this code:

static Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

static int maxElem;

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[][] greatLoto;

    System.out.println("Of how many variants will the ticket consist?  ");
    int variants = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Of how many elements will the variants consist? ");
    int elements = sc.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Which value should be considered the maximum value? ");
    maxElem = sc.nextInt() + 1;

    greatLoto = new int[variants][elements];

    System.out.println("Initial values: ");
    show(greatLoto);

    System.out.println("Modifying values...");
    modified(greatLoto);

    System.out.println("Newest values: ");
    show(greatLoto);

}

private static void show(int[][] greatLoto) {
    for (int i = 0; i < greatLoto.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < greatLoto[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print("|" + greatLoto[i][j] + "|");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

private static void modified(int[][] greatLoto) {
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < greatLoto.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < greatLoto[i].length; j++) {

            while (Arrays.asList(greatLoto[i]).contains(r)) {
               r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
            }
            greatLoto[i][j] = r.nextInt(maxElem);;

        }
        System.out.println("");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is more of a comment but too long: don't use random.next() because it forces you to check for uniqueness. Instead fill a list with the valid values and shuffle it:

```
List<Integer> values = new ArrayList<> ();
for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++) values.add(i);
Collections.shuffle(values);
```

Then you can simply iterate over the values and take the j first numbers.

Note that if j is significantly greater than i using the random approach would probably be more efficient.

Comment: you should mention that this is reasonable only if max is pretty small.

Answer (score 0):

You need three loops:

**Loop_1:** Builds an array of size `j` and uses Loop_1B for every field of this array.

**Loop_1B:** Generate an int with `r.nextInt(maxElem)+1;` (it has to be `+1` because `nextInt()` is covering the 0 inclusively and the specified value exclusively). Afterwards check if the number is already used in the array, if yes, run this loop again.

**Loop_2:** Repeats Loop_1 `i` times.

Answer (score 0):

The most minimal change would be:

```
private static void modified(int[][] greatLoto) {
Random r = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
    for (int i = 0; i < greatLoto.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < greatLoto[i].length; j++) {
            do {
                greatLoto[i][j] = r.nextInt(maxElem);
            } while (Arrays.asList(greatLoto[i]).contains(greatLoto[i][j]));    
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }

}
```

But there are more elegant (but difficult to code) ways to generate unique random numbers without discarding duplicates.

Comment: It has to be `r.nextInt(maxElem)+1;` because OP wants to have the `maxElem` included...